# Why does the Android GPS-Fix vary by 200 ms?

Tags: android, ios, gps

I am writing my Master thesis atm and analyzed about 400 different GPS-Trajectories (paths consisting of a list of longitude/latitude points and an according timestamp) recorded with the MediaQ-App (probably not important) for Android (about 310 trajectories) and iOS (about 90).

When analyzing the time intervals between the timestamps, I was expecting the inaccuracies around the 1 second frequency, in which the timestamps were supposed to be recorded, since neither Android or iOs are real-Time-OS from apps point of view. Still, why are there, what appears to be local peaks in about 200ms steps?  Be nice, I do not know a lot about mobile operating systems :-)

[image: The image shows the (already normalized) probability of the accuracy of a gps timestamp]

(x-axis: seconds, y-axis: the relative probability that a timestamp will be recorded at this point in time. Ignore the exact values of the y-axis...)

Comment: What exactly do you measure: The location time as given in the location stamp (CLLocation), or the system time, or the difference betwen location and system time. Or do you measure the intervalls of systime time at moment of receiving the location event? At ios the difference between two consecutive location time stamps is exactly 1000ms, but not the interfvalls of system time at moment of receiving the location event.

Comment: Hey AlexWien, thanks for your answer!

I am measuring the difference between two consecutive timestamps of a trajectory. I get my data from a database, to which the trajectories have been uploaded. Sadly enough, I have no exact insight, as to how exactly this timestamp is being created, since I have no access to the original source(s). The overall quality of the MediaQ-apps is "not performing  up to standard", to put it mildly. So would you say that this is a programming error?

Answer (score 1):

The usual behavior is that an App takes the timestamp direct from the location delivered by the system. Most probably this is the case in that App, otheriwse this would be a heavy programming bug. (The delay between nominal GPS time and receiving system time of about 200ms is plausible, I saw that in my app, and in ios Map app, which makes a correction in their map api to extrapolate the location into the future, to try to compensate that delay)

Under android (and ios) it is import to know whether the location are determined exclusively by GPS. On both plattforms (ios, android) an App can set whether GPS only or combined GPS + WLAN + Cell Locationing is used.

For high quality recording is is highly recomended to use GPS only.

A GPS chip once having a location usually outputs a location with a timestamp exactly at 000. Exception can happen before the location is valid.
Under ios if the location was obtained by GPS the millisecond are always 0.
I have no experience with android, but usually the GPS chip itself sets the value to millis = 0. (However, some android phones are known to use a crippled cheap GPS chips, that are not able to get an intial position without the help of an internet conection)
It is possible to determine whether the location was obtained by GPS by looking at the course (or called heading) and speed value, which are invalid for non GPS locations (cell Tower locationing)
To know whether this time variations come from the Application (not using the GPS only mode) or if it is caused by Android, you can test that with another application on the same phone. (E.g Motion-X GPS) (Or by comparing both apps on another android phone)